# Getting SIGABRT when trying to update a realm object in swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Warning: I am new to iOS, Swift, and Realm.  I have no problems saving and retrieving with Realm, but I can't seem to update existing objects without crashing.

AppDelegate:

```
class Bale: Object {
    dynamic var uid = NSUUID().UUIDString
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var number = 0
    dynamic var type = 0
    dynamic var weight = 0
    dynamic var size = ""
    dynamic var notes = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "uid"
    }
}
```

Elsewhere: (xcode insisted on all of the !)

```
    let bale: Bale = getBaleByIndex(baleSelected)
    bale.id = Int(textID.text!)!
    bale.number = Int(textNumber.text!)!
    bale.type = Int(textType.text!)!
    bale.weight = Int(textWeight.text!)!
    bale.size = textSize.text!
    bale.notes = textNotes.text!

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(bale, update: true)
    }
```

getBaleByIndex:

```
func getBaleByIndex(index: Int) -> Bale {
    return bales[index]
}
```

I read data from the Bale object returned by getBaleByIndex somewhere else, so that function works fine.  I get the SIGABRT on ***class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {***. There are no full examples showing an update in the realm documentation or examples.  I've also tried using realm.create and appropriate parameters, but still a no go.  It looks simple, so I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.  Any help would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: How are you adding the objects the first time? Where do you get this bales array? sharing more code might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is biting you here is that once you added an object to the Realm, the data isn't stored just in memory, but instead directly in the persistent store. You have to do all your modifcations to your object in the write transaction and they will automatically take effect after the write transaction was committed. There is no need to add it to the Realm again, if it was persisted before. So you'd need to change your code to something like:

```
try! realm.write {
    let bale: Bale = getBaleByIndex(baleSelected)
    bale.id = Int(textID.text!)!
    bale.number = Int(textNumber.text!)!
    bale.type = Int(textType.text!)!
    bale.weight = Int(textWeight.text!)!
    bale.size = textSize.text!
    bale.notes = textNotes.text!

    // Not needed, but depends on the implementation of `getBaleByIndex`
    // and whether there is the guarantee that it always returns already
    // persisted objects.
    //realm.add(bale, update: true)
}
```

Comment: This did the trick for me.  According to the Realm docs, the .add with update:true should add it if it doesn't already exist and edit existing if it does already exist (based on the primary key, UUID, that is in the object).  I may not be doing it exactly the way they recommend, but your solution edits and saves the data as I'd hoped.

Comment: That works only if you're working with a new instance, which isn't persisted yet. So if you don't need to merge with existing properties, you could alternativey instantiate just a new `Bale()` instead of retrieving any existing one first by `getBaleByIndex`.